# Python csv to json using pandas - csv columns to nested json

Tags: python, pandas

**Python 3.8.5 with Pandas 1.1.3**

I have a csv file with columns: name, city, state, and zipcode.  I need to convert to json with the city, state, and zipcode column values inside an object called residence.

For example:

CSV file

```
Name        City    State  Zipcode
John Doe    Akron   OH     44140
```

I need the JSON output to be structured like:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "residence" : 
        {
        "city": "Akron",
        "state": "OH",
        "zipcode": 44140
        }
}
```

I currently use Pandas to convert csv to json using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep = ",", header = 0, index_col = False))
csv_file.to_json("data.json", orient = "records", lines = True, date_format = "iso", double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)
```

As-is, that just converts each column to a json key:value.

How can I add to this code to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Does your csv have only 1 row of data? or does it have several? If the latter, how would you return the JSON?

Comment: @QuangHoang no it has thousands of rows. The parameter `lines = True` is used to output each csv row to a json object on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try creating the nested object row-wise first, then creating the JSON:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv_file = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",",
                       header=0, index_col=False)

# Create Nested dict (Object)
csv_file['Residence'] = csv_file[['City', 'State', 'Zipcode']].apply(
    lambda s: s.to_dict(), axis=1
)
# Write out Name and Residence Only
csv_file[['Name', 'Residence']].to_json("data.json", orient="records",
                                        lines=True, date_format="iso",
                                        double_precision=10, force_ascii=True,
                                        date_unit="ms", default_handler=None)
```

data.csv

```
Name,City,State,Zipcode
John Doe,Akron,OH,44140
Jane Smith,Los Angeles,California,90005
```

data.json

```
{"Name":"John Doe","Residence":{"City":"Akron","State":"OH","Zipcode":44140}}
{"Name":"Jane Smith","Residence":{"City":"Los Angeles","State":"California","Zipcode":90005}}
```

Comment: Looks like that could work - where would your first code block (for creating the nested object) occur in my python example?

Comment: Right after `read_csv`. I updated the answer to include the full code.

Comment: I know this is out of scope and would be considered "bonus," but how can I ensure `zipcode` is output to json as a string instead of integer?  I'm trying to call the `str` method in a couple different places in my code, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: before nesting code after read `csv_file['Zipcode'] = csv_file['Zipcode'].astype(str)`